# Facebook Messenger Page webhook missing

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I was create new app and for testing purposes I using Ngrok, for generating temporary URLs for my localhost, everytime it expires I must in app change that URL. Apps before have a option to subscribe again to different URL, but now I cannot change it.

It shows me only few options without page subscription and in Messenger Settings I can only add another permissions to my app. No way to change URL of page subscription. My solution for now is deleting apps and creating new.

Any new changes in this platform? Week ago I was develop apps with pages permissions without any problem and change it periodically.

Now I see only this:
[image]

Any help, or solution?

Comment: Same here. This is so frustrating!

Comment: I guess this is the reason: https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/03/cracking-down-on-platform-abuse/

Comment: you messenger app is working well ? can you give some brief.